# Existence of direct sum decomposition for any subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let X be a vector space. Let U be any subvectorspace in X. In finite dimensions we know that there exists V subvectorspace of X such that
\begin{align}
U\oplus V = X
\end{align}

i.e. X is a direct sum of U and V. The proof in finite dimensions works through extending the basis of U to a basis of X by joining linearly independent vectors to the basis for U at every step. The basis for V is then provided by the vectors that are appended in this process.
However I can't see you being able to extend this proof to infinite dimensions. But it still very much seems like it should be true, so does anyone have an idea on how to proceed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* true in general that given a vector subspace $U$ of a vector space $X$ one can find a complementary subspace $V$, i.e. one such that $X = U \oplus V$. However this is not as immediate as one would hope, requiring some version of the axiom of choice.

Let $q:X \rightarrow X/U$ be the quotient map. Then the idea is to construct a linear map $s:X/U\rightarrow X$, in the opposite direction, such that $q\circ s = \mathrm{id}_{X/U}$. It is then easy to check that $V=\mathrm{im}(s)$ is a complementary subspace to $U$.

Constructing such an $s$ is not too hard: one lets $(v_\lambda)_{\lambda\in I}$ be a basis of $X/U$ (whose existence is guaranteed by the axiom of choice), and then lets $s(v_\lambda)$ be any one lift of $v_\lambda$ to $X$.

The upshot is that a complementary subspace $V$ always exists, but in general is very much not canonical; you may not be able to pin one down explicitly as is usually the case with such axiom of choice arguments.